# How To Get Rid Of Grafana?

Tags: package-management

I feel very dumb for having to ask this but I'm simply stumped.

I've got grafana running on my box.  I mean when I enter http://localhost:3000 in my browser I see a grafana log in.

```
sudo apt-get remove grafana 

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package grafana

sudo apt-get remove grafana-enterprise

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package grafana-enterprise
```

(I didn't really think I had grafana-enterprise installed).
Also tried:

```
sudo apt-get --purge remove grafana
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package grafana
```

I list everything installed via the snap store and there's no grafana.  So I thought, "well if I can just disable the service so I can use localhost:3000 for another purpose--that's not ideal but it'll work"

```
sudo systemctl status grafana-server
Unit grafana-server.service could not be found.

sudo service grafana-server status
Unit grafana-server.service could not be found.
```

By the way, I see this (among other things) at the bottom of the login screen on localhost:3000

```
Open Source | v9.1.2 (3c13120cde)
```

So no doubt it's Grafana v9.1.2 OS

I know I'm missing something very dumb and obvious but for the life of me I can't figure it out.  Any suggestions of other stuff to check?

Comment: You should post that as an answer @ArturMeinild!  I hadn't considered that and that looks like it's the issue!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another obvious way to get Grafana running is with Docker. This can be confirmed by running `docker ps`. The output could then be like something like:

```
CONTAINER ID   NAMES                  IMAGE                                 CREATED AT                       STATUS
5770a2561f5c   nextcloud-office       collabora/code:latest                 2023-06-13 18:42:01 +0200 CEST   Up 5 hours
9b41de5eec34   nextcloud-cloud        linuxserver/nextcloud:latest          2023-06-13 18:41:59 +0200 CEST   Up 5 hours
293e74450730   grafana                grafana/grafana-oss:latest            2023-06-13 14:03:10 +0200 CEST   Up 10 hours
```

Then, to remove Grafana, first stop the container, and then remove it:

```
docker stop grafana
docker rm grafana
```

Finally, it can be a good idea to remove unused Docker components once in a while. This is done with the following command:

```
docker system prune --all
```

This command will ask for confirmation and remove all components not currently in use (actually you can omit `docker rm grafana` if you do a prune after the container is stopped).

Comment: That's it!  I feel so dumb for not having considered the possibility!  Thanks again for the help!